# Only execute gradlew lint on one job

Tags: android, travis-ci

I'm using the following configuration to create 3 jobs in Travis:

```
env:
  matrix:
    - ANDROID_SDKS=android-17,sysimg-17 ANDROID_TARGET=android-17 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    - ANDROID_SDKS=android-18,sysimg-18 ANDROID_TARGET=android-18 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
    - ANDROID_SDKS=sysimg-19            ANDROID_TARGET=android-19 ANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
```

For these three jobs, I'm running `./gradlew connectedCheck`.

However, I also want to run `./gradlew lint`. But as this command is not dependent of an SDK, I only want to run `lint` in one job (say, the third). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
- if [[ $ANDROID_TARGET = android-19 ]]; then ./gradlew lint; fi
```